# WPF Printing Issue: why are my PageMediaSize settings being ignored?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

In my WPF application I have a xaml page that I would like to print. Page width is 454 pixels and page height is 794 pixels.
The page size comes from the size of the paper I want to use which is 12cm wide (454 pixels) and 21cm high (794 pixels).

Below is the code:

```
 public void Print()
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if(printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
            printDialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(454, 794);

            printDialog.PrintVisual(this, $"Ricevuta {ReceiptToPrint.CustomerFullName}");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the PageMediaSize settings are ignored and the printer prints as if there was an A4 paper inside the drawer. So the xaml page to be printed is placed in the upper left corner of a non-existent A4 paper with the result that only a part of the xaml page to be printed is printed on my custom paper.

I also add that the printer I use supports custom paper sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help. Taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6158fd9-8843-4ab7-b516-f583b99dde6d/changing-printcapabilities-paper-size-or-define-a-new-one-inside-a-printticket?forum=wpf).
I had a similar problem when using XPS printing.

```
XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(mPrintQueue);
PrintTicket ticket = new PrintTicket();
ticket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.Unknown, width, height);

writer.Write(pages, ticket); // in some cases did not work
```

I used the XpsDocumentWriter's WritingPrintTicketRequired event handler to force a PrintTicket while printing a document:

```
writer.WritingPrintTicketRequired += (s, e) =>
{
    e.CurrentPrintTicket = ticket;
};
writer.Write(pages);
```